# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Api\WP_Error' not found in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the WordPress login form and I want to Limit Login Attempts for that form without the use of any plugin. I found the code on this link:

```
https://phppot.com/wordpress/how-to-limit-login-attempts-in-wordpress/
```

I have added this code in the functions.php file but when I try to login it shows me

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Api\WP_Error' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(287)

I try to find a solution for this issue but didn't get any proper solution.

Comment: Could you add a backslash infront of `WP_Error` so it becomes `return new \WP_Error(...)`. I'm assuming you've set the `namespace` of `functions.php` to be `Api`

Comment: @Reece thanks for your reply. that backslash worked. I appriciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set `return new \WP_Error` It's should help you. [See here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php)

Comment: Yes that backslash infornt of WP_Error worked. but now the problem is Error has gone but that functionality is not working. means I am trying to login with wrong username and password then to its not showing me any error/message. Do I need to add that code anwhere else? can you help me please?